# Creating a dynamic drop down menu when returning a mySQL result set

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am returning a result set from a mySQL database into a table using 5 columns. So far so good the table is displaying the correct field data. I would like to know how I should go about creating a drop down menu for each row? This will be the 6th column named 'Status' and will consist of three values which will change the appearance of a row. Another thing to mention is that the 'Status' will not be linked to the database. Here is my current code:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM somewhere")
or die (mysql_error());
?>
<table class="table1" >
<h4>Orders</h4>
<tr>
<th>Number</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Ordered By</th>
<th>Supplier</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['Orderno'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['Orderdate'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['Orderedby'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['Supplier'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['totalprice'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['Status'];
echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select>
    <?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     ?>
     <option value = "<?php echo $row['Orderno']?>">
          <?php $row['other']?>
     </option>
     <?php
     }
     ?>
</select>
```

This is only sample. You can use according to your requirements

Comment: Thanks very much for the solutions. The drop down list will contain 3 items which will change the cell colour for each item (a different colour). Could you give me any pointers as to the JS function to use for each option value in the status dropdown. I have a rough idea. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Like this. Note that the `$options` are outside of the loop. I also fixed the position of your `<h4>` tag - it was inside the `<table>` tag before.

```
<?php

function create_select($name, $options = array(), $selected = null)
{
    $html = '<select name="'.$name.'">';
    foreach ($options as $k => $v)
    {
        $html .= '<option value="'.$k.'"';
        if ($k == $selected)
        {
            $html .= ' selected';
        }

        $html .= '>'.$v.'</option>';
    }

            $html .= '</select>';

    return $html;
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM somewhere")
or die (mysql_error());
?>
<h4>Orders</h4>
<table class="table1" >
    <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Ordered By</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
<?php
$options = array(
    'despatched' => 'Despatched',
    'pending' => 'Pending'
    // etc...
);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Orderno'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Orderdate'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Orderedby'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['Supplier'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['totalprice'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo create_select('status_'.$row['id'], $options, $row['Status']);
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM somewhere")
    or die (mysql_error());
    ?>
    <h4>Orders</h4>
    <table class="table1" >
        <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Ordered By</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['Orderno'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['Orderdate'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['Orderedby'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['Supplier'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['totalprice'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo '  <select id="'.$row['Orderno'].'" onchange="myJSFunction(this)">
                    <option>Example</option>
                    <option>Example 2</option>
                </select>';
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Then write a JS function myJSFunction to handle the change event.

Comment: Thanks very much for the solutions. The drop down list will contain 3 items which will change the cell colour for each item (a different colour). Could you give me any pointers as to the JS function to use for each option value in the status dropdown. I have a rough idea. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
<select class="form-control" name="job_sector" id="job_sector">
            <?php
                $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                for ($i=0;$i<$num_results;$i++) {
                  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                  $name = $row['job_title'];
                  echo '<option value="' .$name. '">' .$name. '</option>';
                  }
            ?>
```