# Highlighting a row of table cells using a drop down select menu

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I've been struggling to find a solution to achieve this. I have an HTML form populated with data from a database. The table consists of 6 columns, one column is named 'Status' which has a drop down menu in each of the cells underneath. The menu consist of three values 'Pending' 'Approved' and 'Disapproved' when a user selects a value from the dropdown all cells on that row should change colour (Green - Approved , Amber - Pending , Red - Dissapproved)

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Orders")
or die (mysql_error());
?>
<table class="table1" style="background-color:#ffffff;" >
<h4>Purchase Orders</h4>
<tr>
<th>Order Number</th>
<th>Order Date</th>
<th>Ordered By</th>
<th>Supplier</th>
<th>Total Price</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['Orderno'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['Orderdate'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['Orderedby'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['Supplier'];
echo "</td><td>£";
echo $row['totalprice'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo '  <select id="'.$row['Orderno'].'" onchange="myJSFunction(this)">
<option></option>
<option>Approved</option>
<option>Pending</option>
<option>Disapproved</option>                  
</select>';
echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

It would be greatly appreciated if somebody could point me in the right direction. How to create three functions for each colour change and then apply them to each option value. If I apply to Orderno, will all cells on that row be affected?

Comment: you should paste your actual generated HTML, not the PHP code

Comment: How is this different from the last question you asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180492/creating-a-dynamic-drop-down-menu-when-returning-a-mysql-result-set?

Comment: if you enjoy answers from prev q-ns you have to accept them

Comment: Apologies it is very similar. I just wanted to know how to trigger the change when each option is selected. Something I didn't quite get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you didn't tag your question with jQuery, however if it is an option, you can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var color = ['none', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'];
    $('table.table1').on('change','select', function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').css('background', color[$(':selected', this).index()]);
    });​
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eQNp5/1/)**

Comment: Thank you very much for the solutions, How would I implement this into the php code? at the moment I am including the Javascript into the <head> tags of the page and then calling the function in the script like:                                                            echo '<select id="'.$row['Orderno'].'" onchange="myJSFunction(this)"> and for the other example: <select onchange="myJSFunction(this)"> however the row colours are not changing. thanks again

Comment: First thing is you'd need to include the jQuery library in the head of the page and follow it with the above chunk of code. After that it should work.

Comment: ok thanks, like this? <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script> and then another set of script tags? How will this be called when i create the <select> box? thank you

Comment: Correct. It will be called automatically when the select box changes. The only issue is that the above code is set to run on all select boxes on the page. If you have select boxes that you don't want it to be attached to, you can specify this using a class, ID, or combination of parent elements.

Comment: ok Thank you. The select boxes are generated dynamically in the table when a new record is added to the database. So it may be difficult to specify a class?

Comment: I updated the code in my answer (not the fiddle) to reflect the dynamically created select boxes.

Comment: Thanks very much this worked perfectly. Is there a way to keep the cells highlighted when the page is refreshed, or when a user logs out? would this be achieved by using cookies? or HTML 5 local storage?

Comment: Correct. You'd need to use cookies, localstorage, sessions or a database to store the changes between visits.

Comment: how would this be implemented in the jquery function if i were to use cookies? Thank you

Comment: I think that answer would be too long to fit into a comment. You'd probably want to start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pXvQG/10/)):

```
function myJSFunction(element)
{
    var row = element.parentNode.parentNode;

    switch(element.options[element.selectedIndex].innerHTML)
    {
        case "Pending":
            row.style.background = "#FF7E00";
            break;
        case "Approved":
            row.style.background = "green";
            break;
        case "Disapproved":
            row.style.background = "red";
            break;
        default:
            row.style.background = "white";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, however I cannot see the fields change colour when each option value is selected. I implemented the above code into the <script> tags of my document. The select box looks like this:     echo "</td><td>";
           echo '  <select onchange="myJSFunction(this)">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>Approved</option>
                    <option>Pending</option>
                    <option>Disapproved</option>
                </select>';
           echo "</td></tr>";
         }
           echo "</table>";

Comment: Sorry I mean implementing this example: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eQNp5/1/ into my current script did not function. Thank you

Comment: Did you include the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library? You can either download it and include it in your code locally, or you can link to a hosted copy of it by putting this in your <head> section: `<script type=text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`. You also need to put that code into a `$(document).ready()` function so that it doesn't execute until the page has loaded.

Comment: Hi j08691, Thanks very much for the new solution. This worked when creating a table, however I cannot get it to work in my php code. I will go through the steps i've taken. Firstly I included jquery on my page using.                                                                     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: then the function: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var color = ['none', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'];
    $('table.table1').on('change','select', function() {
        $(this).parents('td').css('background', color[$(':selected', this).index()]);
    });​
});
    </script>

Comment: php code:<table class="table1" style="background-color:#ffffff;" > and then  select option further down:  echo "</td><td>";
           echo $row['totalprice'];
           echo "</td><td>";
           echo ' <select name="Select1">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>Approved</option>
                    <option>Pending</option>
                    <option>Dissaproved</option>
                </select>';
           echo "</td></tr>";
         }
           echo "</table>";                   sorry to keep this going, i just can't get my head around it. Thanks again

Comment: It makes no difference to your jQuery code whether the content was generated by PHP or if you hand-wrote it yourself. That's handled on the server-side, before jQuery executes. Try loading your page in a browser and view the source. See if you find anything unexpected there. If you can't figure it out, put that output up on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), and it might not be a bad idea to make another for your PHP source code. Post the link to those pastes here and I will have a look.

Comment: Thanks very much this worked perfectly. Is there a way to keep the cells highlighted when the page is refreshed, or when a user logs out? would this be achieved by using cookies? or HTML 5 local storage?